# Is there a place for poker room account trading?

Tags: poker-rooms

I'm looking for an account trading place. Account trading topic on few big poker forums I know leads to ban or a thread removal.

Answer (score 2):

> Account trading topic on few big poker forums I know leads to ban or a thread removal.

Rightly so. Basically, account trading means what it says: you play in the place of somebody else and vice-versa. This practice is banned because it creates traders an unfair advantage which, long term, leads to everybody quitting the game.

I don't think you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: You are wrong. I already have found some: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=234.0 Still looking for another places to buy a poker room acc

Comment: Okay then. Watch out not to get yourself banned from the poker account.